# Do moz-behaviors work in Firefox 10?

Tags: css, firefox, dhtml, xbl

I downloaded an [example of moz-behaviors usage](http://dean.edwards.name/download/#moz-behaviors.xml) but it doesn't work in Firefox 10. Do I need to change something to make it work?

Comment: this "patch" is released before Firefox 10...

Comment: so,why this sample doesnt work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, web pages can no longer use XBL as of Firefox 4 (the support was [removed along with the support for remote XUL](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=546857)). It is possible to [enable both remote XUL and XBL for specific web sites](https://addons.mozilla.org/addon/remote-xul-manager/) but you cannot expect users to do that - so essentially moz-behaviors no longer works.