# Why doesn't -moz-binding work in my code?

Tags: css, firefox, dhtml, dhtmlx

I have a file `SolarCalendar.htc`, its contents are below:

```xml
<script language="javascript">
//My java Script Code
</script>

<public:property put=fnPutDay                  get=fnGetDay                name="day">
<public:property put=fnPutMonth                get=fnGetMonth              name="month">
<public:property put=fnPutYear                 get=fnGetYear               name="year">
<public:property put=fnPutMonthLength          get=fnGetMonthLength        name="monthLength">
<public:property put=fnPutDayLength            get=fnGetDayLength          name="dayLength">
<public:property put=fnPutFirstDay             get=fnGetFirstDay           name="firstDay">
<public:property put=fnPutGridCellEffect       get=fnGetGridCellEffect     name="gridCellEffect">
<public:property put=fnPutGridLinesColor       get=fnGetGridLinesColor     name="gridLinesColor">
<public:property put=fnPutShowDateSelectors    get=fnGetShowDateSelectors  name="showDateSelectors">
<public:property put=fnPutShowDays             get=fnGetShowDays           name="showDays">
<public:property put=fnPutShowTitle            get=fnGetShowTitle          name="showTitle">
<public:property put=fnPutShowVerticalGrid     get=fnGetShowVerticalGrid   name="showVerticalGrid">
<public:property put=fnPutShowHorizontalGrid   get=fnGetShowHorizontalGrid name="showHorizontalGrid">
<public:property put=fnPutValue                get=fnGetValue              name="value">
<public:property put=fnPutValueIsNull          get=fnGetValueIsNull        name="valueIsNull">
<public:property put=fnPutReadOnly             get=fnGetReadOnly           name="readOnly">
<public:property put=fnPutHoliday              get=fnGetHoliday            name="holiday">

<public:event id="onChange"         name="onchange">
<public:event id="onPropertyChange" name="onpropertychange">
<public:event id="onError"          name="onerror">
```

And I have `SolarCalendar.htm` file that uses this 'SolarCalendar.htc' as follows:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html XMLNS:IE>
    <head>
        <meta content="Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 7.1" name="GENERATOR">
        <meta content="http://schemas.microsoft.com/intellisense/ie5" name="vs_targetSchema">
        <STYLE> IE\:Calendar  
            {
                behavior: url(SolarCalendar.htc) ;
                -moz-binding: url(bindings.xml#SolarCalendar.htc);
                 width : 100%; 
             }
        </STYLE>

    </head>
    <body onkeypress="Window_Keypress()" onload="Window_Onload()" onunload="Window_OnUnload()">
        <CENTER><IE:CALENDAR id="cal"></IE:CALENDAR></CENTER>
    </body>
</html>
```

But it doesn't work in FireFox (it works on IE). Do you know what is wrong in this code? I used `bindings.xml` in my project and simple examples with it work well, but the above code doesn't.

Comment: What does the title of your question have to do with the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Can Firefox select your custom HTML element?

Does your selector for the `<IE:CALENDAR>` element work? You could try using the following styles, instead of the `-moz-binding` rule, and see if they have any effect:

```
IE\:Calendar {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: block;
    background-color: green;
}
```

If not, the selector (`IE\:Calendar`) may be the problem.

#### Is your filename correct?

Here’s your [-moz-binding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-binding) line:

```
-moz-binding: url(bindings.xml#SolarCalendar.htc);
```

If I understand correctly, that says:

> Find the file “bindings.xml”, and within it, find the element with an `id` attribute of `SolarCalendar.htc`.

If your file is called “SolarCalendar.htc”, then Firefox won’t find it, because it’s not called “bindings.xml”.

Maybe you could take the XML content out of SolarCalendar.htc, and save it in a file called bindings.xml? Then remove `#SolarCalendar.htc` from your `-moz-binding` rule?

Comment: D.Waite, yes,you're right.I just copy-paste from another place.I have my SolarCalendar.htc ,chould you tell me what I should write in 'SolarCalendar.htm' to work in firefix too?

Comment: @vesna: I’m saying you need a file called “bindings.xml”, and you need to put the XBL code (I’m guessing that all the `<public:>` tags are XBL, but I’m not familiar with XBL so I don’t actually know) into that file. Where did you get your original example code from?

Comment: thanks @D.Waite I understand you.this code had been in project from past and works fine for years in IE.now my company decided that the  project should works in FF,and I dont know how to use DHTML in firefox,and what changes I should do in code!!

Comment: @vesna: aha, oh dear, that doesn’t sound fun at all. I saw from [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679527/do-moz-behaviors-work-in-firefox-10) that Dean Edwards’ moz-behaviours script was an option for earlier versions of Firefox, but that XBL is no longer supported in web pages in Firefox. I don’t think there’s any other way to get the .htc code to work directly in Firefox — .htc is a Microsoft thing that other browsers haven’t adopted.

Comment: @vesna: I’m not exactly sure what your .htc file does, but you might want to look at using an alternative widget in Firefox, e.g. [jQuery UI’s datepicker widget](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/)? Or [YUI’s](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/calendar/)?

Comment: D.Waite, thanks,but I have to change this code,could you tell me how to use .htc file in FireFox?if you get a sample I could handle it.

Comment: @vesna: Firefox does not support .htc. .htc is a Microsoft thing that other browsers haven’t adopted.